# How to use the three steps of Jenkins Warnings Next Generation Plugin properly?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, software-quality, warnings-next-generation

The Jenkins Warnings Next Generation Plugin's [documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/warnings-ng/) for pipelines specifies three step variants:

- `publishIssues`: Publish issues created by a static analysis scan
- `recordIssues`: Record compiler warnings and static analysis results
- `scanForIssues`: Scan files or the console log for warnings or issues

I've just tried this simple snippet out:

```
stage('QA checks') {
    steps {
        recordIssues([
            enabledForFailure: true,
            tools: [php()]
        ])
    }
}
```

and got the result displayed on the build's page ("PHP Runtime: No warnings"). But then what is the sense of the other two steps?

What is a proper way of configuring the plugin? Should these three parts be used, like this?

```
stage('QA checks') {
    steps {
        scanForIssues([...])
        recordIssues([...])
        publishIssues([...])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Came here for the same question. Figured it out from the docs. https://github.com/jenkinsci/warnings-ng-plugin/blob/master/doc/Documentation.md

In summary, the `recordIssues` command is intended to be used alone for simple usecases while the `scanForIssues` and `publishIssues` commands are intended to be used together for more complex usecases.

So your usage of `recordIssues` seems perfectly in line with the authors intent.

From the [documentation](https://github.com/jenkinsci/warnings-ng-plugin/blob/master/doc/Documentation.md#advanced-pipeline-configuration):

> **Advanced Pipeline configuration**
>
> Sometimes publishing and reporting issues using a single step is not
>   sufficient. E.g., if you build your product using several parallel
>   steps and you want to combine the issues from all of these steps into
>   a single result. Then you need to split scanning and aggregation. The
>   plugin provides the following two steps:
>
> - `scanForIssues`: this step scans a report file or the console log with a particular parser and creates an intermediate
>     [AnnotatedReport](https://github.com/jenkinsci/warnings-ng-plugin/blob/master/plugin/src/main/java/io/jenkins/plugins/analysis/core/steps/AnnotatedReport.java)
>     object that contains the report. [...]
> - `publishIssues`: this step publishes a new report in your build that contains the aggregated results of several scanForIssues steps. [...]

Answer (score 3):

As addition to the accepted answer maybe a bit about how to use the plugin.

The official [Jenkins step documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/warnings-ng/) is also a great place to have a look on the Warnings NG plugin. The following examples are from the [Warnings NG Github repo](https://github.com/jenkinsci/warnings-ng-plugin/blob/master/doc/Documentation.md#pipeline-configuration).

---

> publishIssues: Publish issues created by a static analysis scan

```
publishIssues issues: [checkstyle]
```

---

> recordIssues: Record compiler warnings and static analysis results

```
recordIssues enabledForFailure: true, aggregatingResults: true, tool: checkStyle(pattern: 'checkstyle-result.xml')
```

---

> scanForIssues: Scan files or the console log for warnings or issues

```
scanForIssues tool: checkStyle(pattern: '**/target/checkstyle-result.xml')
```

---

The following example should show the difference between `scanForIssues` and `publishIssues`.

```
sh "${mvnHome}/bin/mvn --batch-mode -V -U -e checkstyle:checkstyle pmd:pmd pmd:cpd findbugs:findbugs"

def checkstyle = scanForIssues tool: checkStyle(pattern: '**/target/checkstyle-result.xml')
publishIssues issues: [checkstyle]
```